# Почему блоки стеновые, а не стенные?

Tags: терминология

Есть такой строительный термин "стеновые блоки" — это листы из пвх или других материалов, которыми обшивают стены в помещениях. Но почему они стеновые, а не стенные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Почему" сказать обычно не представляется возможным. Тем более, когда речь идет о терминологии. Просто в данной сфере сложилось такое употребление. Во всяком случае употребление прилагательного "стенной" в значении "то, из чего делают стены" никак русскому языку не противоречит.  
Но, возможно, кому-то когда-то показалось, что именно смыслоразличительная функция тут будет не лишней, ибо "стенной" это в первую очередь "настенный" и подобное. Тем более, есть прямая аналогия: ценный-ценовой. Последнее тоже некогда считалось профжаргоном, но сейчас всеми словарями признается общеупотребительным в соответствующем значении. 
Возможно, и "стеновой" когда-нибудь войдет в обиход.

Answer (score 5):

Это паронимы. Их различают, помимо написания, оттенки значения. 
**СТЕННО́Й** - 1. прил. к стена в 1 и 2 знач. Стенной выступ. 2. ***Предназначенный для висения, вывешивания на стене*** (см. стена в 1 знач.). ***Стенные часы. Стенной календарь***. (Толковый словарь Ушакова)  
**СТЕННО́Й** -а́я, -о́е. 1. к Стена́ (1-3 зн.). С. выступ. С. карниз. С-ая ниша. С. шкаф. 2. ***Предназначенный для помещения на стене***. С-ые часы. С. коврик. С-ое зеркало. С-ая газета…
dic.academic.ru › Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт

**СТЕНОВО́Й** - **Спец.** Предназначенный ***для сооружения стен*** (1 зн.). С-ые материалы. С. кирпич. С-ые блоки.
dic.academic.ru › Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт

Comment: Таки включили ужо?  
ну, сопсно, я это и предполагал... Интересно, когда это произошло - и по чьему наущению.